# 3d thread index and parallelization 2 questions

Tags: c, cuda

I am creating 2d data to produce images.

I am scanning across all columns and rows and get an image.

Now , I want to parallelize this and get a number of slices (images) at the same time.

That's why I want to take into account another dimension in which I will store the different slices I want to obtain.

So ,my first question is how can I do this (like below) in 3d ?

```
RowIdx = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y * blockIdx.y;
ColIdx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
```

Also , in the c code I have something like:

```
size_t RowIdx,ColIdx,theIJ;
float * t2DArrRe,
  * t2DArrIm;

theJ = 0;
for ( RowIdx = 0; RowIdx < NRows; RowIdx++ )
{

    // boundary effect
    *(t2DArrRe + theJ) = 0.0f;
    *(t2DArrIm + theJ) = 1.0f;
   ...
    ++theIJ;
    ...
        }
```

In the above code ,I am taking into account the boundaries of an image (rows and columns) and make some calculations using neighboor positions.

I am not sure how to handle   "theJ"  in the parallel approach.

I hope it is clear,thanks!

---------UPDATE----------------------

Maybe I need something like :

```
RowIdx = threadIdx.y +  blockDim.y * threadIdx.x + (blockDim.y * blockDim.x) * threadIdx.z;
ColIdx = threadIdx.x +  blockDim.x * threadIdx.y + (blockDim.x * blockDim.y) * threadIdx.z;
```

I am not sure if it is right and still I don't know what to do with "theJ".

Is this `theJ += gridDim.x * blockDim.x` enough?

How I will consider all the dimensions of the  grid?

Answer (score 1):

There's a third component on cuda for the third dimension, you could reshape your problem as:

```
Pos_x = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
Pos_y = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y * blockIdx.y;
Pos_z = threadIdx.z + blockDim.z * blockIdx.z;
```

The second part of your problem is unclear for me, but I think that could be an answer:

```
size_t RowIdx,ColIdx,theIJ;
float * t2DArrRe,
  * t2DArrIm;

theJ = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
for ( RowIdx = 0; RowIdx < NRows; RowIdx++ )
{

    // boundary effect
    *(t2DArrRe + theJ) = 0.0f;
    *(t2DArrIm + theJ) = 1.0f;
   ...
    theJ += gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
    ...
        }
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: :Hello , I am not sure then (if I use the Pos_z and not some other thread indexing which takes into account the extra value I want) how I should handle the loop.(check here please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22274647/take-a-number-of-slices ).Also,for the "theJ" does it matter if it would be gridDim.x * blockDim.x or gridDim.y * blockDim.y?

Comment: :Maybe I should do sth like this ? theRowIdx = threadIdx.y +  blockDim.y * threadIdx.x + (blockDim.y * blockDim.x) * threadIdx.z; and theColIdx = threadIdx.x +  blockDim.x * threadIdx.y + (blockDim.x * blockDim.y) * threadIdx.z;

Comment: :But then ,how can I insert the slices into my problem?

Comment: For "theJ", it depends how you want to shaped your grid. I was suggesting gridDim.x * blockDim.x if and only if your grid was shaped on one axe x.

Comment: :So,any ideas for putting together all these?

Comment: No I'm sorry because it's confused for me